# NodeJS. Dealing with � characters encoding

Tags: node.js, character-encoding

I'm having difficulties dealing with character encoding. I'm trying to scrape the following url:

```
http://www.google.com/movies?near=Montreal&date=0
```

My code looks like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var Iconv  = require('iconv').Iconv;

var location = 'montreal';

var googleMovies = url.parse("http://www.google.com/movies?near=" + location);

var req = http.request(googleMovies, function(response) {
    var str = '';
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        str += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {

        var iconv = new Iconv('latin1', 'UTF-8');
        str = iconv.convert(str).toString();

        console.log(str);
    });
});
req.end()
```

I've first tried without:

```
    var iconv = new Iconv('latin1', 'UTF-8');
    str = iconv.convert(str).toString();
```

but that was causing the � characters.

I've tested the source listed above on this page:

http://nlp.fi.muni.cz/projects/chared/

and it seem to detect it as latin1, but things could be wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The � characters come from the concatenation:

```
response.on('data', function(chunk) {
    str += chunk;
});
```

This converts each `chunk` to a `String` with the [default `encoding` of `utf8`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end). Any sequences in the `Buffer`s that aren't valid as UTF-8 will be lost and replaced by � at this point.

You'll want to leave the `chunk`s as `Buffer`s until after the `convert()`. They can be collected in an `Array` and combined with [`Buffer.concat()`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength).

```
var chunks = [];

response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
});

response.on('end', function () {
    var iconv = new Iconv('latin1', 'UTF-8');
    var str = iconv.convert(Buffer.concat(chunks)).toString();
    console.log(str);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set your `User-Agent` to that of a desktop browser, the meta tag in the HTML and the `Content-Type` in the response headers will have the `charset` set to UTF-8 instead of latin1. Example:

```
var dest = url.parse('http://www.google.com/movies?near=montreal');
dest.headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36',
};

http.get(dest, function(response) {
  var str = '';

  response.on('data', function(chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  }).on('end', function() {
    console.log(str);
  }).setEncoding('utf8');
});
```

Comment: This solution also works. It looks like the encoding depends the User-Agent (is this normal?). I prefer @Jonathan Lonowski's solution as it explains better the charset conversion while yours focuses on fixing the source output of this specific service.

Comment: It's more common than it probably should be but lots of backends check the `User-Agent` and change behavior accordingly (e.g. travel sites changing prices based on your OS, sites sending only resources known to work with the browser, etc).

Answer (score 1):

A `Buffer`'s default encoding is UTF-8, which is a variable-width encoding system. Characters after the ASCII range are encoded using multiple bytes. If you're receiving latin1-specific characters (codepoints > 127), they'll have the first bit set, which a UTF-8 decoder will consider as a multi-byte character, eventually resulting in an unmapped codepoint (displayed as �).

`iconv` has a streaming decoder that you can pipe your response stream to.

```
http.request(googleMovies, function (response) {
    var iconv = new Iconv('latin1', 'UTF-8');
    response.pipe(iconv).pipe(process.stdout);
    //or response.pipe(iconv).on('data', console.log);
}).end();
```

Comment: Your solution appears elegant and I think it should work, but for some reason it does not. Can you test and see if it works for you ?

Comment: I was `console.log`ging the arguments received in `end` event and not the `data` event. Piping to `process.stdout` should also work.

Comment: Thanks, now it works, it dumps the data into stdout. Do you have a way to pipe this into a string that could be used for further manipulation ? I need a 'str' variable to work with it further. All solutions I found regarding "piping into string" are similar to @Jonathan Lonowski's example.

Comment: You'll have to use the same approach you were using: listen for `data`, concat, and use the string on `end`. Only this time you'll have to attach listeners to `iconv`.